# MATLAB plot displays Latin letters, instead of Greek

Tags: matlab, plot

I need to have Greek symbols in my plot. I have the following code so far.

```
imshow(img);
axis on;
axis([0, 300, 0, 300]);
set(gca, 'XAxisLocation','top');
set (gca,'FontName','Symbol');
hx = xlabel({'\phi -->'});
hy = ylabel('<-- \rho');
```

However, in the figure, `\phi` is translated to `f` and `\rho` to `r`. How to correct this issue?

The interpreter is TeX.

```
>>>get(hx, 'Interpreter')

ans = 

tex
```

Comment: @StewieGriffin `$\phi$` is translated to `$f$`

Comment: `set (gca,'FontName','Symbol');` comment this line?

Comment: Try changig the interpreter to latex. Maybe that will work? By the way, your code worked for me.

Comment: @StewieGriffin changing the interpreter worked. would u like to post an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the interpreter to `latex` does the trick. Following code results in proper rendering.

```
imshow(img);
axis on;
axis([0, 300, 0, 300]);
set(gca, 'XAxisLocation','top');
xlabel('$\phi \longrightarrow$','interpreter','latex')
ylabel('$\longleftarrow \rho$','interpreter','latex');
```

According to [matlab documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html), `interpreter` can have 3 values:

'tex' — Interpret characters using a subset of TeX markup.

'latex' — Interpret characters using LaTeX markup.

'none' — Display literal characters.

Looks like 'tex' mode does not include displaying greek symbols!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :-)